# Soft ensembling voting with machine learning algorithms for multiple predictions in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I would like to build up a soft ensembling voting algorithms to predict 4 types. I knew some packages (such as caretStack)for ensembling methods, but they are good for binary predictions. And i found a good example as what i expected with Python(https://www.kaggle.com/code/scratchpad/notebook00214fe8b3/edit).

I would like to know if there is a suitable package of method in R to achieve my purpose, such as what the Python tutorial did, with Cross-validation and constructing ensembling models (such as combine kNN, RF, NB, .etc) for prediction.

[image]